# How to migrate column type DOUBLE via cakephp phinx migrations?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, migration, phinx

I'm trying to migrate table from db1 to db2 with using [Phinx](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/index.html) migrations, but i have  a problem with one table where i have column type `DOUBLE`. I know that supported types are there [Phinx column type](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#working-with-columns), but it is possible to specify `FLOAT` type to get `DOUBLE` in diff_migration ? I use cakephp version 3.5.6.

My example migration_diff

```
<?php
   use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

   class Diff003 extends AbstractMigration
{

public function up()
{

    $this->table('test_double')
        ->addColumn('double1', 'float', [ // here type DOUBLE is changing to  FLOAT
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => null,
            'null' => true,
        ])
        ->addColumn('double2', 'float', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => null,
            'null' => true,
        ])
        ->create();
}

public function down()
{

    $this->dropTable('test_double');
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DOUBLE` type has been implemented recently, and will probably be available in the next Phinx release (it's been added as of version 0.10.7), see **https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/pull/1493**.

Until then you can for example use the [**custom column type feature**](http://docs.phinx.org/en/stable/migrations.html#custom-column-types-default-values):

```
->addColumn('double1', \Phinx\Util\Literal::from('DOUBLE'), [
    // ...
])
```

or manually add the columns via raw SQL, something like:

```
$this->execute('ALTER TABLE test_double ADD COLUMN double1 DOUBLE NULL');
```

or if you're adventurous, use the Phinx master branch until the stable release is available:

```
composer require robmorgan/phinx:dev-master
```

```
->addColumn('double1', 'double', [
    // ...
])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)